# Wrong SCRIPT_FILENAME & PHP_SELF in Apache 2.4.26

Tags: php, environment-variables, apache2.4, fpm

With Apache 2.4.26 using php-fpm 7.1.6, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` (and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`) is incorrect on a folder:

**Apache 2.4.26:**

```
/index.php
```

**Apache 2.4.25:**

```
/myfolder/index.php
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed it in apache config with this new config directive :

```
ProxyFCGIBackendType GENERIC
```

In global configuration before the SetHandler directive. Default is FPM, but it's not correct with some php-fpm configuration (SetHandler and socket).

With this bug all `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` Apache vars (`$_SERVER`) (injected from php-fpm) are wrong, they don't have the path!

ProxyFCGIBackendType is default to FPM but it's wrong for many configuration.
Apache httpd should add GENERIC as default to don't break websites.

See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#proxyfcgibackendtype

Comment: FWIW they are aware of it and working on it for next version.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Added it at the top of the etc/sites-available file

Comment: Do you know how i fix/change this inside a puphpet/vagrant setup?

Comment: @Michael: Add it to your `.htaccess` or to PuPHPet's Virtual Host-Level Custom Directives.

Comment: @leek Thank you, adding it to the htaccess works. But i dont understand what/where i have to change it in "PuPHPet's Virtual Host-Level Custom Directives". Do you mean the config.yaml or one of the files in the puphpet folder?

Comment: Ok i found it. Its puphpet/puppet/modules/apache/templates/httpd.conf.erb

Answer (score 1):

(This would be better as a comment, but I'm under the minimum rep.)

Like neoteknic points out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44657409/6626418), using the `GENERIC` backend type will revert you to 2.4.25 behavior while we get this bug worked out.

Note, however, that the 2.4.25 behavior [breaks some other people too](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/694#issuecomment-267183973) and is not a panacea. If you're in a bind, the new [`ProxyFCGISetEnvIf` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#proxyfcgisetenvif) can give you direct control over FCGI envvars, and it accepts httpd expression syntax for some pretty complex manipulations, if you need them. This only helps if you understand what those envvars are supposed to be, but it's another option.